# Show if an answer is accepted on the network profile

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, network-profile, top-answers

On the [network profile top answers section](https://stackexchange.com/users/3846032/scimonster#top-answers-container), it would make sense to show if the answer is the accepted one.

Over here:

[image: Top answers on network profile]

Perhaps even in the questions section, show if the question has an accepted answer.

Comment: Just to notice, with your rep (from all the accounts), your tops (answers) should be topper ;) consider adding more :)

Comment: I have over 300 answers on SO, just most of them don't reach 5 upvotes.